# To invalidate validation in aftervalidate

Tags: php, model-view-controller, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

cakephp2 -in MODEL

```
public function afterValidate () {
       $ validator = $ this-> validator ();
       if (condition) {
        unset ($ this-> validate [Model] ['target column name']);
         // or
        $ validator-> remove ('target column name');
       }
```

It is said.

This does not release the validator to the target array.

You should be able to remove it with either unset or remove

```
$ this-> validationErrors
```

With this, when I checked the error, I was able to confirm that it was not released.
How do you release it? Also, can't it be canceled in aftervalidate? What is the right thing to do?

Postscript:

```
$ this-> validate
```

When I vardumped it, it was properly unset. However, the validation is on fire. It is displayed in ($ this-> validationErrors).
How can I devalidate?

Comment: You are changing the validator, but only after the data has already been validated?

Comment: omg. I mostly understood that.